# raw text to array python

Tags: python, arrays, text, raw

```
import numpy as np
import re
def read_process_OD():
    OD = np.zeros([24, 24])
    lines=[]
    with open('Network_OD.txt','r') as f:
        lines=f.readlines()
    origin=[]
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('Origin')==True:
            pass
        else:
            origin.append(re.split(pattern=[':;'],string=lines))
```

#raw text is shown like this:
#Origin     1

##### 1 :      0.0;     2 :    100.0;     3 :    100.0;     4 :    500.0;     5 :    ###200.0;

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi brutus, I am trying to convert raw text as a matrix [24,24]. My text has titles, spaces, colons and semicolons. I don't know how to proceed. The lines are ordered by origin destination nodes. for instance: Origin 6: 1:100.0;2:400.0, and on. Origin is the row index, and the data following are the value of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to get from this text is what that is called a "dictionary" in python. So, let's get to the answer.
First, you have to split the text by the ";"

```
splitted_text=raw_text.split(";")
```

you will have:

```
["1 : 0.0", "2 : 100.0", "3 : 100.0", "4 : 500.0", "5 :200.0"]
```

which is not a dictionary, yet. you might have guessed that the next step is splitting each element of the list above by ":". Here, to make the long story short, I will get to the final part:

```
my_dict={}
for i in splitted_text:
    dict[int(i.split(":")[0])]=float(i.split(":")[1])
```

And, by this, you will have a dictionary ready to be analyzed, make graph of , etc. :

```
{1:0.0,2:100.0,3:100.0,4:500.0,5:200.0}
```

Comment: Thank, Hamid!! Can I convert the dictionary into an array after that? the key is the column index.

Comment: Dear Paloma, I believe you have a background in C or Java script. In Python there is no such a thing as "array". If you mean something like: [1,2,4,5]; this is called a list in python.